# TypeScript 'not assignable to typeof never'

Tags: typescript

I have a function written like so:

```
 type ChartData = {
    x?: number[],
    y?: number[],
    z?: string[],
  };

  type RawData = {
    x: number | null | undefined,
    y: number | null | undefined,
    z: string| null | undefined,
  }

  const data: RawData[] = [{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }, { x: 4, y: 7, z: 10 }]; // this is typed

  const formattedData = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    Object.entries(el).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (!acc[k as keyof ChartData]) {
        acc[k as keyof ChartData] = [];
      }
      acc[k as keyof ChartData].push(v);
    });
    return acc;
  }, {} as ChartData);
```

Now there's an issue in that I'm getting the error `Argument of type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' and` Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I believe this is caused by `acc[k as keyof ChartData] = []` but I can't work out how to type this array (I believe it should be a string[] | number[]).

I also do not like having to use `k as keyof ChartData` three times, and I wondered whether there was a better way of doing this also.

Reproducible example: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwE7ACIOAqBeKBvAKCmKgA8AuKAOwFcBbAIwiQG0BdAGiJJEtsebsuJKAC9KAZ2BIAllQDmQ7gF8A3AW6hIUAEoIA7ukw583YhWr0mSKAB9LAGwd2oNKgBMIAMzkR3wnj4rZhdaJxc3Tx8qPwDicSgpWQVQmnD7SO9ffxV1DQBjAHsqKSh3DARKPUMK9hMWPDJKAEYOKF4oACY2hIAiBF6oZTbGiwAWNo6Adh7KXoZB5TY8opLgKC9CpDoMYD8jLFxyzAA6JD8afIgACmuEfPy2iAcAShwAPlNiAHkGACsIPlgCcIFRpDIIBJrs8XidNkgAKL3OC3FgAazaADc2G9sJ9CCIZF4oNcAIT3fLoqAICRQNEQECFYnwZBoCo4r4iakPKk0ukMpmwRAoA5serLMxDSUU3m0%20mM5nCtmYNgnMA0CQozEvdTEZQ67jnYA0JBUbn5dTDfDKam0lkiioGgirCSFBwQE4OQrya7wnbAPbuA46oA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Pass that code through your favorite IDE and fix any typos so that people who want to help don't have to do it themselves.

Comment: (Hints: `RawData` is not an array type.  Your `z` property cannot be both a `number` and a `string`.)

Comment: Aplogies, example added.

Comment: I'm still confused; it sure looks like you might be pushing `null` or `undefined` into a `string[]` or `number[]`.  Why are you not checking `v` in any way?

Comment: I did try adding `if (v != null) before trying to push(v), but it didn't get rid of the issue where I'm trying to assign string to never.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it would fix your problem; I'm saying it's an added problem that gets in the way of demonstrating your issue. Of course it shouldn't let you push `v` unless you make sure it's non-nullish.  Can you [edit] the question to get rid of the whole `null` thing (if `RawData` is not nullable you still have your issue), or write code that actually handles it so that a fix to the `never` problem won't immediately hit that error?

Comment: So, like, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBRedN) resolves the problem but I had to add extra code to check `v`.  Does this work for you?  If so I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for that, the difference between my example and the real code is that `RawData` is a more complex object that comes from an api, so I can't change the `RawData` or `RawDataEntry` as you do. However, I might be able to play around with your example and make it work.

Comment: So, should I write this up as an answer or not?  I tend to write, uh, *thorough* answers, and if I go through that effort and you say "this doesn't work for me, sorry" afterwards then I become sad.  So I'd like to know in advance whether an approach is likely to be acceptable.